# Only show most upvoted in 'related questions'

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just discovered why duplicate questions are not deleted on the SE network. But why do the less popular questions then show up in 'Related' on the right hand side? I keep on seeing questions with -1 or -2 or similar votes in 'Related' list which then turn out to be duplicates.

Can't we fix this by showing only the 'original' question in 'Related'?

If it matters, I was originally searching for 'delete duplicates' after going through 5-6 questions on Math.SE which were EXACT duplicates of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related questions list is filtered foremost on similarity. Those posts are more likely to be helpful to you than the other, higher upvoted questions. That seems a pretty good design in my opinion, since a bad received question can still have very good and useful answers.

The entire path can be very useful in finding out why that question is a duplicate (not very obvious sometimes) and it might have useful answers which you would miss otherwise.

The duplicate question should already appear on top of the question (if it was closed as duplicate) and in the side bar, so I see no use to force that one in the related questions too.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence? I think there's a misunderstanding there.

Comment: What do you mean with this then? "showing only the 'original' answer in 'Related'"

Comment: If 'Related' shows a question with -1 votes, which is a duplicate of another with the original having 15 votes, then 'Related' should directly show the one with 15 votes, or in other words, 'save us a trip'. Sorry for the typo, I've fixed it.

Comment: Why? The entire path can be very useful in finding out why that question is a duplicate (not very obvious sometimes) and it might have useful answers which you would miss otherwise.